# Insert TableLayout with scrollbars inside a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have a Table called "Grid", create inside its own class... like this:

```
ScrollView contentView = new ScrollView(this);
        contentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        // THIS IS OUR MAIN LAYOUT
         mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // ADD MAINLAYOUT TO SCROLLVIEW (contentView)

       contentView.addView(mainLayout);

        // SET CONTENT VIEW

        setContentView(contentView);

        meTable = this.tableLayout();

        HorizontalScrollView HOR = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

        mainLayout.addView(HOR);

        HOR.addView(meTable);
```

This creates the table, and also adds an horizontal and vertical scrollbar, that's great...

However, I need to put all of this inside another RelativeLayout, like this:

[image]

I can do that but without the scrollbars,I just add "meTable", like this:

```
Grid gr = new Grid();
        gr.Activate(this);
        TableLayout tablita;

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.contenedorLay);

        tablita = gr.meTable;


        layout.addView(tablita);
```

How do I add the entire table with their scrollbars?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code, it works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/layout" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"         
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"     
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:fillViewport="true"> 

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/horizontalView" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tlGridTable" >   
        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```